# Java implementing task on another thread with javascript-like promise resolve-reject

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

**Background:**

I have a TCP online multiplayer game server, which the player requests to log-in. However, the game server does not handle the authentication part of the login process, instead, it uses an outer micro-service which is an HTTP server to see if the user can authenticate with the given credentials.

***Now why is that a problem?*** - Well I use [netty.io](https://netty.io/) networking framework, which is a non-blocking framework, it handles all connections in a sequence on the same thread. Since I don't want to cause any delays, I will not send an HTTP request on the same thread because I don't want to stop it.

Instead I followed a pattern of callbacks like java script promise resolve-reject, and I Would like to hear what you think, and if it could be done better.

Don't mind the generic types, just take the basic idea of it:

First of all this is my `ServiceProvider`, the point of this class is to provide a singleton of each service that interacts with microservices such as UserService which is an HTTP server to handle everything related to user (authentication, data, etc):

```
public class ServiceProvider {

    private static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(ServicesConfig.SERVICES_THREAD_POOL_CAPACITY);

    private static UserService userService;

    /**
     * Provdes an user service singleton instance
     * @return  The user service
     */
    public static UserService getUserService() {
        if (userService == null) {
            userService = new UserService();
            userService.setBaseUrl(ServicesConfig.USER_SERVICE_BASE_URL);
        }
        return userService;
    }

    public static void submitServiceTask(ServicePromise task) {
        executorService.submit(task);
    }
}
```

Secondly is my `UserService` for example:

```
public class UserService extends HeroesHttpService {

    /**
     * Authenticates an user
     * @param username  The username
     * @param password  The password
     * @return  ?
     */
    public ServicePromise<?> authenticateUser(String username, String password) {

        ServicePromise<HttpResponse> promise = new ServicePromise<HttpResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(getBaseUrl() + "/user/authenticate");
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    resolve(response);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        ServiceProvider.submitServiceTask(promise);
        return promise;
    }
}
```

Now this is my promise interface:

```
public abstract class ServicePromise<T> implements Runnable {

    private ServicePromiseCallback<T> callback;

    public ServicePromise<T> then(ServicePromiseCallback<T> cb) {
        this.callback = cb;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    }

    public void resolve(T data) {
        if (this.callback == null) {
            return;
        }
        this.callback.onResolve(data);
    }

    public void reject(T data) {
        if (this.callback == null) {
            return;
        }
        this.callback.onReject(data);
    }
}
```

And that's the callback interface:

```
public interface ServicePromiseCallback<T> {
    void onResolve(T response);
    void onReject(T response);
}
```

And finally, thats how I use it:

```
    ServiceProvider.getUserService().authenticateUser(player.playerName, player.playerPass).then(new ServicePromiseCallback<?> () {
        @Override
        public void onResolve(Object response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onReject(Object response) {

        }
    });
```

Again, don't mind the types in resolve/reject, it's going to definitely be `AuthenticateUserResponseDto` and so on, but it doesn't matter right now

Comment: I don't understand the use case: user authentication **should** be a synchronized action. the client must block until user is authenticated. so what kind of "delay" do you want to resolve?

Comment: The client waits for the response, the game server is not an HTTP server, it doesn't wait for a response by protocol, it will just receive a success packet once the process is finished, or failure packet. I don't want to stop the main thread that handles all users for this login request

Comment: You have to look at it like this; You have 1000 users, logging in every time, if you will send a request or bulk of requests every X time, each user has to wait for each login to finish. but if you handle each login request (the call to the user HTTP server) on a different thread, this solves the issue of waiting

Comment: for example player A tries to login, now player B tries to login, but the thread handles player A's http request, thread is locked, therefore B wont execute until A finishes, but what about C, D, E players which are already logged in? they will not receive an update, and in a game server it is important to send update packets otherwise the game will start "lagging" (unless the requests take less than 600ms which is the tick rate) in my game specifically

Comment: please update the question with the new info. it is not specified that this is an online multi player scenario (I was thinking along the lines of online game service like kongregate)

Comment: This is example code, a hypothetical simplification of the real deal, isn't it? Please take a look at our [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `ServiceProvider` is supposed to provide a singleton instance of `UserService` but it does not follow all the principles of the Singleton design pattern. specifically, the locking mechanisms that prevent multiple threads from creating multiple instances of `UserService` (or rather, multiple calling of the constructor)

and while on the subject - why not use [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)?

also, `reject(response)` is never called

with regard to the issue of the "javascript-like promise resolve-reject": Java has such a mechanism: [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) where you supply a `Runnable` and for the callbacks there are `thenApply()` `thenAccept()` and `thenRun()` methods.  exceptions are handled by `exceptionally()` method. There are other capabilities like chaining `CompletableFuture` instances (`thenCompose()`.

Comment: So you are basically saying that multiple threads are going to use that user service reference provided, which may cause a conflict (because I don't synchronize them), should I make it a new instance of user service instead? And I dont use dependecy injeciton because the project is large, adding dependcy injection to it is an hassle, its either use it everywhere or nothing, can't break the convention

Comment: Would love to see an example of firing a Runnable with thread pool Executors and received a CompletableFuture, I had issues with it which took me to a too complicated door

Comment: `UserService` instance is static so there will always be one instance (if you have one class loader) but multiple threads may enter the `if` statement and call the constructor. You should look up singleton design pattern double checked locking mechanism. you should also be aware that in today's software applications singleton are injected.

Comment: there are several tutorials about working with `CompletableFuture` with examples.

Comment: But that shouldn't be a problem should it? all threads read the same state of a reference, if userService is null, it will create new, but only once.

Comment: no. OS causes context switch and makes threads go to sleep. so multiple threads can pass the if statement and go to sleep before the instance is created. you should **really** search and read on design pattern double checked locking to realize multiple threads issues

Comment: Obviously you are right, dependency injection container would be a good choice to go there instead of using singleton I can just use a DI container to provide user service as a singleton injection. However that would require a big refactor since you have to map the DI container from the beginning of the application with guice or spring. I don't really have time for that, that is the main reason I used singleton. on the other hand i can just pass the instance of user service everywhere manually around my app but that can be very confusing don't you agree

Comment: if you gonna stick with singleton, I suggest you initialize the instance in a static block. that would ensure the constructor is called one time only

Comment: you mean init it with static constructor? `static { userService = new ... }` ?

Comment: yes, yes, yes,.

Comment: and if I init it with a static consuturctor does it *ensure* that its initialized before everything and I don't have to use an if statement or any locks when I get the instance with a static method?

Comment: not sure about "before everything". the static block is executed by the class loader when the class is first referenced and is loaded into memory